# How the default template is created when the url of directory hosted on web is hit?

Tags: html, node.js, angularjs, http, server

i have a angularjs module for some common component, services etc with their separate folders, say root/component/, root/services/ and so on. When i hit url "root/component/" in browser, i get a webpage with all subfolders, files in that location. How that html webpage is rendered ? How can i modify such a default webpage ?

[sample screenshot of default template for a directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Whevy.png)

P.S. : Its and angularjs app running on node based express.js server. How can i modify the html ?

Answer (score 0):

> How that html webpage is rendered ?

As with any dynamically generated HTML document: With server-side code.

It's a common feature, but implementation-specific.

Apache HTTPD, for example, uses the [mod_autoindex](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_autoindex.html) module.

> How can i modify such a default webpage ?

Depends on whatever is generating the index.

I linked to the documentation for mod_autoindex above. It lets you do, for example:

```
HeaderName HEADER.html
```

To use the contents of the file `HEADER.html` as the top part of the generated document.

Comment: I am working on an Angularjs app with server as node server. Do you know any particular file or dependency which generates index and renders ?

Comment: Node is a tool to run JavaScript outside of a web browser. There are several web servers written using Node. I've no idea which one you are using.